# why am i getting updated values of table even after using scroll insensitive?

Tags: java

```
package jdbc1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;


public class scrollable extends Thread{
     

       
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            Connection cn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","postgres","123456");
            Statement st=cn1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            st.executeUpdate("update emp set ename='BLAKE2' where empno=7698");
            
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
        
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","postgres","123456");
        Statement st=cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);  
        ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from emp");
        int i=0;
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            
            
            if(i==5)
            {
                
            scrollable obj=new scrollable();
            obj.start();
            obj.join();
            rs1.last();
            rs1.refreshRow();
            
            }
            System.out.println(rs1.getObject(1)+" "+rs1.getString(2));
            i++;
        }
        rs1.close();
    }
}
```

I used `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` in my code and updated the table. Now after refreshing row I should get old values right? But I am getting new values. Here thread is updating table after that I refreshed the row as per insensitive it should not get refreshed and give old values right?

Comment: Class names should begin in uppercase, so they don't get confused with variable names, which start in lowercase.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: "org.postgresql.Driver" type4 driver of postgres